# concat multiple image and multiple video using complex_filter concat and scale simultaneously?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two ffmpeg commands:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i test4.jpg -i test4.jpg -preset ultrafast -vsync vfr -filter_complex "[0:v]fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0];[1:v]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1];[v0][v1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" rd.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i newvideo.mp4 -i videoplayback.mp4 -i newvideo.mp4 -preset ultrafast -vsync vfr -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0]; [1:v]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1];[2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v2]; [v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]" -map [v] rd.mp4
```

How i can combine these two commands?

I want to concatenate **multiple image with different resolutions** and multiple **Videos with different resolutions and bit rate**.

Above two commands work properly but i am not able to combine these two commands in single command.

I tried this command

```
ffmpeg -i newvideo.mp4 -i videoplayback.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i test4.jpg -preset ultrafast -vsync vfr -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v0]; [1:v]scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v1];[2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[v2]; [v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]" -map [v] rd.mp4
```

I just try to add an image end of video with 5 second's duration. **Although it can by any sequence of video and image**

I am getting this error :

```
Input link in2:v0 parameters (size 1280x720, SAR 144000:144001) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1280x720, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_8 @ 0000000002a56520] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_8
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Add setsar filter as shown in links above.